# How to add Custom Arrow heads in react-input-range

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, less

I'm using react-input-range as a slider to select a price range.I have customized the css of the range slider but I need to add arrow heads inside the circles  as follow

[image]

How can I do this.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-multi-slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider#readme) slider component with one or two markers. Options to customize track, touch area and provide customer markers and callbacks for touch events and value changes.

```
<MultiSlider
    ...
    isMarkersSeparated={true}

    customMarkerLeft={(e) => {
         return (<CustomSliderMarkerLeft
          currentValue={e.currentValue}/>)
    }}

    customMarkerRight={(e) => {
         return (<CustomSliderMarkerRight
         currentValue={e.currentValue}/>)
    }}
/>
```